# Why accumulator in spark are write-only for worker task?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming, accumulator

As per the documentation of accumulators:

> Note that tasks on worker nodes cannot access the accumulator’s value()—from the point of view of these tasks, accumulators are write-only variables.

Why does spark provided this nature for accumulators?

Answer (score 0):

Accumulators are not thread-safe. The DAG scheduler that updates the accumulator values is executed on a single thread after a task completes. So if worker node had access(reads) accumulator's value the read value might not be consistent. That is why I think it is designed that way.